# Meteor template helpers fire multiple times

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  // SOME CODE HERE LIKE
  myLove: function() {
    console.log("Fired");
    return "meteor.js";
  }
});
```

What works like a charm... but with one huge problem... when i want to use variable "myLove" in template like 5times (in different places) when i check console it fires multiple times so when i have there database query it runs multipletimes what is definely not good... how to fix it?

BTW: i use handlebars for template.

Comment: If you have N number of documents in your collection, your 'myLove' helpers method will fire N times and fire again when meteor finds changes. http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers

Comment: well its just one findOne method there... can i somehow the result asign to variable and use in template? that would cause stop firing it multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this template in multiple places, the code will be executed multiple times, that's true.

Although, using mongodb cursors calls is safe, Meteor optimizes it and calls identical queries only once (on server) and all calls on client (with minimongo) are cheap.

Comment: Good to know! I redesigned my structure so in the helper is only some logic code now and no query is fired but thx great to know. Marking as answered.