# Meteor template helpers accessed on each call

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-helper

I've read this [Meteor template helpers fire multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349516/meteor-template-helpers-fire-multiple-times) and tried to reproduce this without any collections involved.

So I got helper like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    test: function(){
        console.log("Fired");
        return {
            name : "Foo"
        };
    }
});
```

And template looks like this:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{test.name}}{{test.name}}
</template>
```

In console i expected to see "Fired" only once, but helper is called actually twice ? So if my helper is accessing collection and getting data from there, every time i use {{helper.key}} it performs a query? is this how it should work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right the template system will call a helper for each time you use it in your template.

I guess what you're asking is if this is efficient for collections since they're called again and again.

This is why meteor's `.find()` returns a cursor which is a sort of cache. You can see this if you try and find something with `.find()`, you would get an object but not actually your data. The cursor only fetches data as it is needed so it is not as inefficient as it may seem.

Appending `.fetch()` actually fetches the data and does not use this cache which is why it is less efficient and often suggested not to be used as the `return` value of the helper.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But If I have let's say an edit page for some item and i want to populate input fields with values, so i will be calling {{item.keyOne}}, {{item.keyTwo}} and i will need actual data for that, so fetch() will be called each time then? How that could be solved then ?

Comment: I think you would be calling it once then, following with the cache. Because when you use `item.` you're going to use `findOne()`. Either way the memory use/difference would be insignificant the operational overhead is very low since everything is already in memory

Comment: i am trying to fetch some remote content from another site via api in my helper. For such scenarios?